# Что во что вкладывать - section в article или article в section?

Tags: html5

Ни как не пойму с этими тегами `<section>` и `<article>`.
Здесь утверждают, что `article` - дочерний элемент внутри `section` по DOM.

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781077/html5-best-practices-section-header-aside-article-elements

А здесь утверждают обратное:
цитата:

2. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/702051/important-HTML-Interview-questions-with-answe
3. https://htmlacademy.ru/blog/css/aside-vs-article

> `<article>`: автономный контент.
> `<section>`: используется внутри article для определения разделов или содержимого группы в разделах.

Comment: Используйте синтаксис MarkDown `[описание](ссылка)`. Так легче читаться будет)

Comment: Что такое selection?

Comment: @andreymal , https://htmlbook.ru/html/section

Comment: @andreymal, это очепятка.
Спасибо! Поправил. Даже сам не заметил. Старый я.

Comment: @Глеб, Это что ещё за нововведение? ТОлько только вникать начал в article, section, aside, так ещё и MarkDown - он то для чего? Те теги хоть для слепых (скринридеры) и всякие штуки новомодные в мобильных гаджетах + SEO (как понимаю разбивка по блокам, div видать уже устарел совсем).

Comment: @I_CaR Глеб говорит не про html, а про оформление вопроса на этом сайте

Comment: Допустима и такая вложенность, и такая. Рекомендую для подобных случаев хороший ресурс ```Caninclude```: https://caninclude.glitch.me - меня он не раз выручал